# Keeping agent in the same location when using gotoPopulation

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a population of agents (containers) inside another agent (ship). This is required so that the containers will move with the ship. Once the ship docks, I want the containers to change from the population in 'ship' to the population in 'main' . When I use the following

```
gotoPopulation(main.containers_main);
```

to send a container agent to a population of containers in main, the container will move to 0,0 in the main environment.

The above code is placed in the container agent.

Is there a way to change an agent's population but keep it in the same location?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. As for agents, there is no "same position", they are always relative to something (previously relative to `Ship`, now to `main`).

But you can manually position them at the same (apparent) position by:

1. getting the container's relative position on `main` while still in `Ship`: `getX() + ship.getX()` (same for Y, assuming ship is embedded in Main and container in Ship) --> store briefly as double `myPosX`
2. move to new population on main as you do above
3. set "new" pos relative to Main: `setX(myPosX)`

It sounds cumbersome but makes sense, once you understand that embedded agent positions are always relative to their parent. Remove the parent and you need to account for adjusted the relative position to keep them in the (seemingly) "same" position

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, that makes sense.